# Java Horizontal BoxLayout with Vertical Layout Inside

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

Okay, so I have a BoxLayout set to Y_AXIS for a main panel I have in a JFrame. I tried to set the actual Frame to a BoxLayout set to X_AXIS then add my main panel to my JFrame, but I get an java.awt.AWTError saying: "BoxLayout can't be shared". Is there any other way of using BoxLayout that will allow me to do this?

```
ComponentPanel.setToolTipText("I go in the FramePanel as well as other of my types aligned up and down");

FramePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(FramePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
FramePanel.add(ComponentPanel);

Frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Frame, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
Frame.add(FramePanel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `JFrame`'s content panel as the `BoxLayout`'s target container:

```
frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

Also, *please* try to follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Variable names should start with a lowercase letter; class names should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Okay, thanks abunch I am a little new at this stuff, but I think I am getting the hang of it. I know about the naming convention thing just being lazy :). I read the HeadFirst Java book by orielly. If you have any more suggestions on books please let me know. I am kind of looking for a more advanced book for intermediate programmers. I also have a new problem same error, but I added another panel to the frame aligned to the left of my other panel. I want to maintain the same Y_AXIS orientation though.

Comment: @StoneAgeProgrammer Can't help you with the book question -- I haven't read a Java SE book in a long time sorry (try reading some reviews on Amazon). As for your next issue, if you added a new panel, it needs a _new_ BoxLayout similar to how you set the first panel's layout. You can only have one container per BoxLayout (that's why it takes the container in its constructor)...if you try to add the same layout to multiple panels, you will keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

BoxLayout is "static" in the "new BoxLayout".
Try using a class extending Panel and placing Panel in a package folder to change the *package hierarchy level* to separate the "static field value" class variable Boxlayout.

e.g. class Mypanel extends Panel{.....
which you would import as a package

import separateguipart.Mypanel;

Panel insertboxlayoutpanel = (Panel)new Mypanel();

or use the full classified JNDI name

Panel insertboxlayoutpanel = (Panel)new separateguipart.Mypanel();

insertboxlayoutpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(FramePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing wrong with the code. You just have to import some library which is  import.javax.swing.*;
and import.awt.*;